# Multiple picturesymbol on ArcGIS Map

Tags: android

Hi I want to add multiple pins on the ArcGIS Map. But I am getting only one pin on wrong location. here is the code, I am getting lat long in response and putting in arrayalist and getting it after that here is my AsynkTask for it.

```
    private class AsyncTaskMaps extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        mUtility.showProgress(getActivity(), "Please Wait", "Loading..");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String response = mServiceHandler.getSoapResponseByMethod("GetMap");

        if (response != null) {

            try {
                lstMaps = new ArrayList<InfobeanMaps>();

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray rows = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Rows");
                for (int i = 0; i < rows.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = rows.getJSONObject(i);

                    infoMaps = new InfobeanMaps();

                    String siteName = c.getString("SiteName");
                    infoMaps.setSiteName(siteName);

                    String longitude = c.getString("Longitude");
                    infoMaps.setLongitude(longitude);

                    String latitude = c.getString("Latitude");
                    infoMaps.setLatitude(latitude);

                    String address = c.getString("Address");
                    infoMaps.setAddress(address);

                    String contact = c.getString("Contact");
                    infoMaps.setContact(contact);

                    lstMaps.add(infoMaps);

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (result == null) {
            mUtility.dismissProgress();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Network error",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            mUtility.dismissProgress();
            for (int i = 0; i < lstMaps.size(); i++) {


                Point p = new Point(Double.parseDouble(lstMaps.get(i)
                        .getLongitude()), Double.parseDouble(lstMaps.get(i)
                        .getLatitude())); // Birmingham

                GraphicsLayer graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer(
                        mapView.getSpatialReference(), new Envelope(-180,
                                -90, 180, 90));

                // add marker
                Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin);
                PictureMarkerSymbol picMarker = new PictureMarkerSymbol(d);

                Graphic g = new Graphic(p, picMarker);
                graphicsLayer.addGraphic(g);

                mapView.addLayer(graphicsLayer);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem. I was not converting the lat long to points. here is the solution.

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (result == null) {
            mUtility.dismissProgress();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Network error",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            mUtility.dismissProgress();
            for (int i = 0; i < lstMaps.size(); i++) {

                Point p = new Point(Double.parseDouble(lstMaps.get(i)
                        .getLongitude()), Double.parseDouble(lstMaps.get(i)
                        .getLatitude())); // Birmingham
                Point mapPoint = (Point) GeometryEngine.project(p,
                        SpatialReference.create(4326),
                        mapView.getSpatialReference());

                GraphicsLayer graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer(
                        mapView.getSpatialReference(), new Envelope(-180,
                                -90, 180, 90));

                // add marker
                Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin);
                PictureMarkerSymbol picMarker = new PictureMarkerSymbol(d);

                Graphic g = new Graphic(mapPoint, picMarker);
                graphicsLayer.addGraphic(g);

                mapView.addLayer(graphicsLayer);
            }
        }
    }
}
```